# Error parsing reference: "ubuntu:18.04 as base" is not a valid repository/tag

Tags: docker

I had a dockerfile in a repository for a while now and I built it several times in the past week.

It has this line at the top of the file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder
```

Today I started getting this error:

```
Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder
Error parsing reference: "ubuntu:18.04 AS builder" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

I haven't touched the Dockerfile in that repo in a while. Nobody has touched that file in 5 months.

I ran this command to build it:

```
docker build .
```

Docker version:

```
bash-3.2$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce-rc1, build 3476dbf
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: FROM ubuntu:18.04 works but not FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder

Comment: The error message shows `as` written in lowercase but your top line shows `AS` ... are you sure it is written uppercase?

Comment: I updated my post. I was messing around locally, trying to see if it is `AS` or `as`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker [multi stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) (keyword `AS`) were introduced in 17.06. You are using 17.03, so you need to switch to the newer docker version.

Comment: But nothing on my laptop changed. This was working till Friday.

Comment: I am just guessing here, but maybe these layers were still in cache from an earlier build with a newer docker version or else, but if you want to build with this instruction, you need >=17.06